# Does a full Windows Server backup also backup "previous versions" created by VSS?

Tags: backup, windows, vss, windows-server-backup, windows-server-2012-r2

Let's say I have volume C:\ with VSS enabled, and there is some file `C:\somefile.txt`, which has been around for a while.

- Today, I remove `C:\somefile.txt`. Since VSS is enabled it's still contained in yesterday's VSS snapshot.
- After removing the file, I make a full system backup using Windows Server Backup.
- After the backup, the server is erased.

When restoring the server from the full system backup, is `somefile.txt` still recoverable? In other words, does Windows Server Backup also backup the "previous versions" or only a current snapshot of the system?

---

*Background: I need to delete some sensitive data before taking the backup and I want to make sure that the data cannot be recovered from the backup.*

Comment: Is this a 2012 server or an earlier OS?

Comment: @Colyn1337: Windows Server 2012R2.

Comment: Are you going to use server backup with "storage spaces"?

Comment: @Colyn1337: No. (Would it make a difference?)

Comment: I believe storage spaces has a replication option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows integrated backup use VSS to snapshot the filesystem, then backup the files from this snapshot.

As snapshot can not contain other snapshots, the answer to your question is no.